# How can I set an event using the data from a SQL database

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have written simple programs that show in DataGridView some info. The most important info is the expiration date, which I manage to color it read when the expiration date is near(like 5 days). The person responsible has an email in the database. I use a SQL database.
What is the code to send email only to the persons that their products are near the expiration date?
If I call the function `send_mail()` in the code that colors the line red it sends infinite mails to 1 person.
This is my code:

```vb
    Private Sub dgvExcel_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting

    If CDate(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(DataGridView1.Columns(5).Index).Value) <= Date.Now Then
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
        'send_mail()
    End If

    If CDate(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(DataGridView1.Columns(4).Index).Value) <= Date.Now Then
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, you really shouldnt send an email every time datagridview formats a cell; cell formatting occurs thousands of times over the course of an app run

Comment: This task should be resolved using a service (windows service) that scans the database table at specific intervals and send the mail if needed. Or you can solve it using a job scheduling agent. For example [Quartz.Net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

Comment: Agree with Steve, though given that the app is mostly written, it might be easier to start it with the task scheduler and have it do some work in response to a command line arg

Comment: I prefer to keep these things outside the main app. My two cents

Comment: If you're using SQL Serv,er I suggest you use SQL Agent to check the records once a day and send emails as required

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (BTW, I see no SQL in the question, do you expect an SQL answer?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enumerate the datatable the grid is databind'd to and send an email to the relevant person. This process should be launched on a schedule you specify, such as clicking a button, or when launching the program with a comand line argument

```
For Each ro as DataRow in dataTableToWhichTheDgvIsBound
  If((DateTime.Now - DirectCast(ro("expiration_date"), DateTime)).TotalDays < 5 Then
    SendEmail(ro("owner_email").ToString(), $"Your thing with id{ro("id")} is about to expire on {(ro("expiration_date"):yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm)}" )
Next ro
```

Or, if youre using strongly typed datatables it looks a bit nicer:

```
For Each ro in dataTableToWhichTheDgvIsBound
  If((DateTime.Now - ro.expiration_date).TotalDays < 5 Then
    SendEmail(ro.owner_email, $"Your thing with id{ro.id} is about to expire on {(ro.expiration_date:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm)}" )
Next ro
```

You do this in e.g. a button click or at app startup (after loading the datatable with data0, perhaps by using the `My.Application.CommandLineArgs` to see if it contains an `/autosendexpiryemails` argument etc